# What is the best way to test a condition in Linq to NHibernate?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

The Any() linq function seems to load all of the entity's columns even though they're not needed.

The following code:

```
if(Session.Query<Project>().Any(p=>p.ID == projectID && p.ProjectOwner.Responsible == CurrentUserID))
    // Current user is the responsible for this project
```

Generates the following SQL:

```
select TOP (1) project0_.ProjectID                          as ProjectID7_,
               project0_.DateCreated                        as DateCrea2_7_,
               project0_.Type                               as Type7_,
               project0_.ProjectOwner_FK                    as ProjectOy8_7_,
               project0_.Address_FK                         as Address9_7_,

**[Snip -- the statement selects all of Project's columns]**

from   [Project] project0_
       inner join [OrganizationProject] organizati1_
         on project0_.ProjectOwner_FK = organizati1_.OrganizationProjectID
where  project0_.ProjectID = 1 /* @p0 */
       and organizati1_.Responsible_FK = 1 /* @p1 */
```

However, the following code:

```
if(Context.Projects.Where(p=>p.ID == projectID && p.ProjectOwner.Responsible == CurrentUserID).Count() == 1)
    // Current user is the responsible for this project
```

Generates the following sql, which is what is expected:

```
select cast(count(*) as INT) as col_0_0_
from   [Project] project0_
       inner join [OrganizationProject] organizati1_
         on project0_.ProjectOwner_FK = organizati1_.OrganizationProjectID
where  project0_.ProjectID = 1 /* @p0 */
       and organizati1_.Responsible_FK = 1 /* @p1 */
```

The Count() method does what is expected, but it is a bit less straightforward.

Is the Any() behavior considered normal or is it a bug? It doesn't seem optimal to me, but maybe loading the entity isn't really slower than asking SQL to return the count?

In light of this, **what is considered to be the best way to test a condition in Linq to NHibernate?**

Comment: I suspect that you would need to benchmark it to find out which is fastest. It's possible that loading all the fields from any one result (and note that there is no sort, so it could really be any row) is faster than performing the join then counting the size of the full result set.

Comment: I agree with @Douglas: I see no reason why your second query would be faster. With proper indexes, first query basically uses an index seek.

Comment: It still has to retrieve the 20 column values from disk and send them to the client though... and then NHibernate needs to instanciate the entity and fill it with the data or is that not significant? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was interesting but did you tryed:

```
if(Session.Query<Project>()
   .FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ID == projectID 
                 && p.ProjectOwner.Responsible == CurrentUserID) != null)
```

I think it would be faster from your current options. In fact it doesn't checks for all items (like count) Also it doesn't fetch all data.

Comment: Doesn't FirstOrDefault loads the entity though (fetch the column data from the DB)? If so it's the same as Any() except with a different, slightly less intuitive syntax...

Comment: @Tsuushin, Yes it loads entity, Also you can try something else like: `Session.Query<Project>()
   .Count(p=>p.ID == projectID 
                 && p.ProjectOwner.Responsible == CurrentUserID)`, It's trade of, calling `Any` is not bad, because no data will be transferred from server to client, data transfer is just between server and DB and is not time consuming job. Also just one entity will be transferred from DB to server.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should create a query with only a single column:

```
if(Session
    .Query<Project>()
    .Where(p=>p.ID == projectID && p.ProjectOwner.Responsible == CurrentUserID)
    .Select(p=>new { pID = p.ID })
    .Any())
{
   ...
}
```

Projection to an anonymous type allows NHibernate to fetch only the specified column (ID, for example).

But it is usually more suitable when there is a significant number of rows to retrieve.

Comment: I guess I could refactor that into an extension method, take an IQueryable containing the test to execute, add the Select statement dynamically and call Any on it... Not a very ideal solution though :/